# How can a desktop software communicate with a browser form (jsp, php, etc ...)

Tags: php, html, forms, jsp, browser

I need an advice on how to create (if at all possible) a desktop software that will populate a browser form (php, jsp, etc...).

For instance, here is the  [link to create a new google gmail account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=en)
What I'd like my "future desktop software" to do is to populate the fields on that web page as much as possible.

How can I do that, if at all possible ?  And also I'm planning to create the application with Java or C#. Let me know if another technology would be more appropriate to create that desktop application

(ultimately the desktop app is going to be a interface with a database BUT this is not my concern for the current question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big security concern letting an application communicate directly with the browser. What the commonly used browsers have, are extensions which allow you to implement those things into the browser. Even if you are going to develop an extra desktop software, you will be able to communicate to the application with the browser extension. You probably should have a look at these links:

[Build Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

[Build Firefox add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons)

Comment: So what you mean is I'll have the add-on being the interface between my desktop application and the form in the browser ? Actually I want a one-to-one relationship between the browser forms fields and the desktop application form fields. Is it going to be possible with the add-on ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to handle the communication between the application and the add-on yourself. The add-on is installed by you, so it has access to things happening in the browser, which you don't have without add-on because of security reasons. Otherwise every application could just see whats happening in your browser and change things without your consent. In Short: To get the form structure, the add-on gets the information from the webpage, passes it somewhere to a local or remote interface where your desktop application has access to. To fill in the data it goes the other way round.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna start working on it. I'll let you know if I create something GOOD.